# RStudio standalone connecting to HDFS

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, rstudio

I am having a standalone installation of R and RStudio on my laptop (Windown / Mac) and a Hadoop cluster installed remotely (Linux). I would like to connect to HDFS from RStudio to read data, do the processing and then finally, if required, push the results back to HDFS.

I am not very sure whether this is possible or it only needs a server version of RStudio? Can anyone please suggest on whats the best alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it a secure cluster? If it isn't the [rwebHDFS package](https://github.com/saurfang/rwebhdfs) solves this problem. Using it you can use the following code to connect to a remote cluster:

```
library(rwebhdfs)
hdfs <- webhdfs("<hdfs-webfs-node>", 50070, "<user>")
f <- read_file(hdfs, "/<path>/<to>/<file>")
```

The packages relies on RCurl, which has limitations (libcurl v1.0.0o on Windows) when used with a secure cluster. To access using a secure cluster I would use the `httr` package and query the cluster directly using the [WebHDFS REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)

```
# WebHDFS url
hdfsUri <- "http://namenodedns:port/webhdfs/v1"
# Uri of the file you want to read
fileUri <- "/user/username/myfile.csv"
# Optional parameter, with the format &name1=value1&name2=value2
optionnalParameters <- ""

# OPEN => read a file
readParameter <- "?op=OPEN"

# Concatenate all the parameters into one uri
uri <- paste0(hdfsUri, fileUri, readParameter, optionnalParameters)

# Read your file with the function you want as long as it supports reading from a connection
data <- read.csv(uri)
```

**Code taken directly from [link](https://github.com/saagie/example-R-read-and-write-from-hdfs/blob/master/read.R)**

There is no reason to get RStudio Server. I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Both works fine for me, thank you.  The first one doesn't return a table, it just returns plain text fetched from the csv. And the second reads the csv correctly but it doesn't fetch all the data just 20 lines, i think there is a parameter to load all the file.